# Using TypedADT constructs in Inox

Tags: scala, leon

The inox documentation states the following

> Inox provides the utility types TypedADTSort and TypedADTConstructor
>   (see file inox/ast/Definitions.scala) that correspond to ADT
>   definitions whose type parameters have been instantiated with concrete
>   types. One can use these to access parameters/fields and enclosed
>   expressions with instantiated types.

The following object contains the sorts and constructors necessary for modelling a mathematical field.

```
import inox._
import inox.trees.{forall => _, _}
import inox.trees.dsl._

import welder._

object Field { 
  /*
    A non trivial field has elements different from zero.
    We can further assume the existence of a nonzero element called one.
    Any other element is of type notOne.

    field -> zero
          -> nonZero -> one
                     -> notOne
  */

  val element = FreshIdentifier("element")
  val zero = FreshIdentifier("zero")
  val nonZero = FreshIdentifier("nonZero")
  val one = FreshIdentifier("one")
  val notOne = FreshIdentifier("notOne")

  val elementADT = mkSort(element)()(Seq(zero, one, nonZero, notOne))
  val nonZeroADT = mkConstructor(nonZero)()(Some(element)) {_ => Seq()}
  val zeroADT = mkConstructor(zero)()(Some(element)) {_ => Seq()}
  val oneADT = mkConstructor(one)()(Some(nonZero)) {_ => Seq()}
  val notOneADT = mkConstructor(notOne)()(Some(nonZero)) {_ => Seq()}


  val symbols = NoSymbols
    .withADTs(Seq(elementADT, nonZeroADT, zeroADT, oneADT, notOneADT))
    .withFunctions(Seq(/*Register functions*/))

  val program = InoxProgram(Context.empty, symbols)

  val theory = theoryOf(program)
  import theory._
}
```

Now I introduce the sorts and constructs for modelling affine points of an elliptic curve.

```
import inox._
import inox.trees.{forall => _, _}
import inox.trees.dsl._

import welder._

object Curve {

  val F: ADTType = T(Field.element)()
  val affinePoint = FreshIdentifier("affinePoint")
  val infinitePoint = FreshIdentifier("infinitePoint")
  val finitePoint = FreshIdentifier("finitePoint")
  val x = FreshIdentifier("x")
  val y = FreshIdentifier("y")

  val affinePointADT = mkSort(affinePoint)("F")(Seq(infinitePoint,finitePoint))
  val infiniteADT = mkConstructor(infinitePoint)("F")(Some(affinePoint))(_ => Seq())
  val finiteADT = mkConstructor(finitePoint)("F")(Some(affinePoint)){ case Seq(fT) =>
    Seq(ValDef(x, fT), ValDef(y, fT))
  }

  val affine = TypedADTSort(affinePointADT,Seq(F))
  val infinite = TypedADTConstructor(infiniteADT,Seq(F))
  val finite = TypedADTConstructor(finiteADT,Seq(F))

  val symbols = NoSymbols
    .withADTs(Seq(affinePointADT, infiniteADT, finiteADT))
    .withFunctions(Seq(/*Register functions here*/))
}
```

You can observe that at the end I'm using `TypedADTSort` and `TypedADTConstructor` to use the field elements as parameter instead of a generic parameter. I need this to talk about operations on field elements in the context of affine points.

**Compile error**

Compiling this gives an error of the type

```
could not find implicit value for parameter symbols: inox.trees.Symbols
[error]   val affine = TypedADTSort(affinePointADT,Seq(F))
[error]                            ^
could not find implicit value for parameter symbols: inox.trees.Symbols
[error]   val infinite = TypedADTConstructor(infiniteADT,Seq(F))
```

Why does this happen? What solutions are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use the TypedADT construct in this case. It suffices to model the following hierarchy with sorts and constructors.

```
abstract class Element
abstract class AffinePoint[T]
```

The hard part is perhaps realizing that `AffinePoint[Element]` can be modeled as `T(affinePoint)(T(element)())` using the Inox DSL in [here](https://github.com/epfl-lara/inox/blob/master/src/main/scala/inox/ast/DSL.scala).

In any case, the compile error that I get arises from the fact that I need to pass an implicit argument to the corresponding call.